# cadr wrong type argument listp

Tags: package, debugging

I have this code that used to work fine until today:

```
(let* ((newest-pkg (cadr (assq 'org package-archive-contents)))
       (installed-pkg (cadr (or (assq 'org package-alist)
                               (assq 'org package--builtins)))))
  (when (version-list-<= (package-desc-version newest-pkg) (package-desc-version installed-pkg))
    ;; Instalamos la nueva versión de org-mode
    ;;(package-install newest-pkg)
    (message (format "Paquete «%s» actualizado de la versión %s a la versión %s"
                     (package-desc-name newest-pkg)
                     (car (package-desc-version newest-pkg))
                     (car (package-desc-version installed-pkg))))
    ;;(delete-directory (package-desc-dir installed-pkg) t)
    ))
```

However, it is failing with this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp [nil nil "Outline-based notes management and organizer"])
  cadr((org . [nil nil "Outline-based notes management and organizer"]))
  (let* ((newest-pkg (cadr (assq (quote org) package-archive-contents))) (installed-pkg (cadr (or (assq (quote org) package-alist) (assq (quote org) package--builtins))))) (if (version-list-<= (progn (or (and (memq (aref newest-pkg 0) cl-struct-package-desc-tags)) (error "%s accessing a non-%s" (quote package-desc-version) (quote package-desc))) (aref newest-pkg 2)) (progn (or (and (memq (aref installed-pkg 0) cl-struct-package-desc-tags)) (error "%s accessing a non-%s" (quote package-desc-version) (quote package-desc))) (aref installed-pkg 2))) (progn (message (format "Paquete «%s» actualizado de la versión %s a la versión %s" (progn (or (and ...) (error "%s accessing a non-%s" ... ...)) (aref newest-pkg 1)) (car (progn (or ... ...) (aref newest-pkg 2))) (car (progn (or ... ...) (aref installed-pkg 2))))))))
  eval((let* ((newest-pkg (cadr (assq (quote org) package-archive-contents))) (installed-pkg (cadr (or (assq (quote org) package-alist) (assq (quote org) package--builtins))))) (if (version-list-<= (progn (or (and (memq (aref newest-pkg 0) cl-struct-package-desc-tags)) (error "%s accessing a non-%s" (quote package-desc-version) (quote package-desc))) (aref newest-pkg 2)) (progn (or (and (memq (aref installed-pkg 0) cl-struct-package-desc-tags)) (error "%s accessing a non-%s" (quote package-desc-version) (quote package-desc))) (aref installed-pkg 2))) (progn (message (format "Paquete «%s» actualizado de la versión %s a la versión %s" (progn (or (and ...) (error "%s accessing a non-%s" ... ...)) (aref newest-pkg 1)) (car (progn (or ... ...) (aref newest-pkg 2))) (car (progn (or ... ...) (aref installed-pkg 2)))))))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This is how I'm setting the package archive.

```
(setf package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
(setf package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                         ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

My Emacs version is GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.6) of 2016-06-04 on juergen.

Comment: What is your emacs version and how are you setting up packages repositories? (e.g. what is the value of `package-archives` and do you call `package-refresh-contents` prior to this? etc.)  It appears as though your `package-archive-contents` might contain a list of conses instead of a list of lists, which I can't reproduce on emacs 24.5

Comment: @nispio I edited the question, and I call that code after `package-refresh-contents`.

Comment: Still unable to reproduce.  You might consider wiping out `~/.emacs.d/elpa` and restarting emacs to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: You could insert a call to `(debug)` in that code, or if it is in a function you can you could just use `M-x debug-on-entry` for that function. You can put `(debug)` into the first `let*` binding using `progn`: `(progn (debug) (newest-pkg (cadr (assq 'org package-archive-contents))))`. Then step through the debugger to see which `cadr` is the problem. That might give you a clue. But I'd start by doing what @nispio suggested - simplify your debugging context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the following three variables, they have slightly different formats:

> `package-archive-contents`
>
> This is an alist mapping package names (symbols) to non-empty lists of `package-desc' structures.
>
> `package-alist`
>
> Each element has the form (PKG . DESCS), where PKG is a package name (a symbol) and DESCS is a non-empty list of `package-desc'structure, sorted by decreasing versions.
>
> `package--builtins`
>
> Each element has the form (PKG . PACKAGE-BI-DESC), where PKG is a package name (a symbol) and DESC is a `package--bi-desc' structure.

So `package--builtins` needs to be handled a little differently because the `cdr` of each element is not a list like the other two.  Instead, you should be able to make it work like this:

```el
(let* ((newest-pkg (car-safe (cdr (assq 'org package-archive-contents))))
       (new-ver (and newest-pkg (package-desc-version newest-pkg)))
       (builtin-pkg (cdr (assq 'org package--builtins)))
       (installed-pkg (car-safe (cdr (assq 'org package-alist))))
       (old-dir (and installed-pkg (package-desc-dir installed-pkg)))
       (old-ver (or (and installed-pkg (package-desc-version installed-pkg))
                    (and builtin-pkg (package--bi-desc-version builtin-pkg)))))
  (when (and new-ver (version-list-< old-ver new-ver))
    ;; Instalamos la nueva versión de org-mode
    ;;(package-install newest-pkg)
    (message (format "Paquete «%s» actualizado de la versión %s a la versión %s"
                     (package-desc-name newest-pkg) old-ver new-ver))
    ;; (when old-dir (delete-directory old-dir t))
    ))
```

Comment: I'm getting a different error this time: ```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "package-desc-version accessing a non-package-desc")
  signal(error ("package-desc-version accessing a non-package-desc"))
  error("%s accessing a non-%s" package-desc-version package-desc)```

Comment: I'm using `package-desc-p` just to be sure that `installed-pkg` is a valid `package-desc`

Comment: @shackra I have updated the code to add in a large amount of error checking along the way.

Comment: I was trying by my own too but things didn't worked out, this is a function I made for using inside `let*` for the `installed-pkg` variable: ```(defun shackra/update--one-package-installed-package-installed (package)
  "Retorna un PACKAGE-DESC valido"
  (or (car-safe (cdr (assq package package-alist)))
     (if (package-desc-p (cdr (assq package package--builtins)))
         (cdr (assq package package--builtins))
       (package-desc-create :name (format "%s" package) :version (list 0 0)))))```

Comment: btw, you misspelled `pakcage-desc-version`

Comment: Since `package--builtins` contains structures of type `package--bi-desc`, you can expect `(package-desc-p (cdr (assq package package--builtins)))` to always be false.